# insert menu items in ascending order and vertically in Toolstripmenuitem

Tags: c#, toolstripdropdown, toolstripmenu, toolstripitem

I have a inserted items in the toolstripmenuitem control successfully. But i am not able to rearrange items as shown below :-

For ex :-
Currently Items are added in toolstripmenuitem like below fashion:-

```
aa bb cc dd
ee ff gg hh
```

But i want like this :-

```
aa ee
bb ff
cc gg
dd hh
```

My code is :-

```
private void CreateEnterpriseHierarchy(ToolStripMenuItem selectToolStripMenuItem)
    {
        try
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem entToolStripMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            var enterprise = CurrentUserContext.ECPTree.Where(x => x.ImageIndex == 0).FirstOrDefault();
            if (enterprise != null)
            {
                entToolStripMenuItem.Tag = enterprise;
                entToolStripMenuItem.ToolTipText = entToolStripMenuItem.Name = entToolStripMenuItem.Text = enterprise.Name;
                //entToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = enterprise.IsNodeEnabled;
                //newToolStripMenuItem.Image = 
                entToolStripMenuItem.Image = this.imgListMenu.Images[0];
                CreateCompanyList(entToolStripMenuItem, enterprise);
            }
            else
            {
                entToolStripMenuItem.Text = "---------";
            }

            // To open Hierarchy of Enterprise - Companies and Properties with Multiple Columns

            ToolStripDropDown menu = new ToolStripDropDown();
            ToolStripItem[] items = new ToolStripItem[entToolStripMenuItem.DropDown.Items.Count];
            entToolStripMenuItem.DropDown.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);

            // Transfer the items into the drop-down menu.
            foreach (ToolStripItem item in items)
            {
                if (!(item is ToolStripSeparator)) menu.Items.Add(item);
            }

            // Adjust the layout of the new menu.
            menu.LayoutStyle = ToolStripLayoutStyle.Table;
            ((TableLayoutSettings)menu.LayoutSettings).ColumnCount = 6;

            // Attach it to the menu.
            entToolStripMenuItem.DropDown = menu;

            selectToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(entToolStripMenuItem);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CusException cex = new CusException(ex);
            cex.Show(MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

and the Method CreateCompanyList:-

```
void CreateCompanyList(ToolStripMenuItem selectedMenuItem, SCTreeView Enterprise)
    {
        try
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem enterpiseMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            enterpiseMenuItem.Text = selectedMenuItem.Text;
            enterpiseMenuItem.Tag = selectedMenuItem.Tag;
            enterpiseMenuItem.Name = enterpiseMenuItem.Text = selectedMenuItem.Name;
            enterpiseMenuItem.Enabled = Enterprise.IsNodeEnabled;
            enterpiseMenuItem.ImageIndex = 0;
            enterpiseMenuItem.Image = this.imgListMenu.Images[0];
            enterpiseMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(DisplaySelectedLevel);
            selectedMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(enterpiseMenuItem);
            selectedMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
            foreach (var item in CurrentUserContext.ECPTree)
            {
                if (item.ImageIndex == 1)
                {
                    ToolStripMenuItem companyMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
                    companyMenuItem.Tag = item;
                    companyMenuItem.Name = companyMenuItem.Text = item.Name;
                    // companyMenuItem.Enabled = item.IsNodeEnabled;
                    var lstProperties = CurrentUserContext.ECPTree.Where(x => x.ParentID == item.ID).ToList();
                    if (lstProperties.Count == 0)
                    {
                        companyMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(DisplaySelectedLevel);
                    }
                    companyMenuItem.ImageIndex = item.ImageIndex;
                    companyMenuItem.Image = this.imgListMenu.Images[1];
                    selectedMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(companyMenuItem);

                    CreatePropertyList(item, companyMenuItem);
                }
            }
            if (selectedMenuItem.DropDown.Height > 500)
            {
                selectedMenuItem.DropDown.AutoSize = true;
                selectedMenuItem.DropDown.Height = 500;
            }
            selectedMenuItem.DropDownDirection = ToolStripDropDownDirection.Default;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CusException cex = new CusException(ex);
            cex.Show(MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Is there some way to achieve the desired layout style ?

Any help or idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard .Net menu bar is a little bit messy especially when it comes to vertical displays.

Apply these values to your main menu bar properties:

- TextDirection: Vertical90
- LayoutStyle: VerticalStackWithOverflow
- Dock: Left

This will make your menu bar bigger than what you expected, but it is relied on its items `width`. When you want to add your menu remember to specify its width.

Comment: Hi MahanGM ! where should i apply these attributes ?

Comment: @user2691432 I assume you have a main menu strip which you put all of your sub menus in it. Anywhere your root menu is getting created, you should apply them to that menu.